# Add icon in b-button-group component in bootstrap-vue?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I checked the documentation [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/button-group/#dropdown-menu-support) but seems there is no detail on how to add an icon in `b-button-group` button, thou I can add text. Does anybody know any easy way how to do it ?

Below is my code:

```
  <b-button-group>
    <b-dropdown
      size="sm"
      right
      variant="primary"
      split
      text="Features"
      v-on:click="$router.push({...})"
    >
      <b-dropdown-item>Item 1</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item>Item 2</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-divider></b-dropdown-divider>
      <b-dropdown-item>Item 3</b-dropdown-item>
    </b-dropdown>
  </b-button-group>
```

I would like to add this `<b-icon :icon="'arrows-expand'"></b-icon>Features` in the text but seems there is no way because of course `text` only accepts raw text.

Comment: answer works great, in your case just do: `<template slot="button-content"> <b-icon :icon="'arrows-expand'"></b-icon> Features </template>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found the answer to another page in the documentation where I can use the slot as below:

```
   <template v-slot:button-content>
      Custom <strong>Content</strong> with <em>HTML</em> via Slot
    </template>
```

https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/dropdown